# Tagged ports on HP switch VLANs

Tags: hp, switch, vlan, hp-procurve

wondering if somebody more experienced with HP procurve switching equipment can answer a pretty basic question for me. I'm trying to segment off 3 ports onto their own little network segment. I configured a vlan, made the 3 ports access ports to that vlan, however when I look at the config, it automatically shows 3 other ports as "tagged", aka "trunk" ports. I did not config them them to be trunk ports for this vlan, it was automatic.

So, can anyone confirm that traffic from these 3 ports won't be able to traverse these trunks?

[image of the vlan configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZcLr.png)

Comment: that pic say untagged port 30,31,32 and connected to a 10 gbit iface and is named ha vlan if i read it correctly

Comment: yea....... i know... I took that screenshot and provided it here for information purposes to somebody who might know the answer to my question.
Turns out that the config was correct and fine as it was.. traffic cant traverse the trunks as it was designed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ports don't traverse trunks. VLANs do (or don't).

If a VLAN is tagged on a port, it's active. If the far side of the link isn't configured in the same way that VLAN's frames are likely dropped there. For good practice, you should remove the VLAN on this side as well: `no vlan 60 tagged <port>`.

Comment: Turns out the config was fine... im guessing since the other end of the link was not configured for vlan60 like you said. However, that command doesn't work for some reason. And when I did find the correct command, it wouldn't let me because the tagged ports "are not access ports".